# using async and await in angular in a loop function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use `async` and `await` function in my code but I'm finding it hard to do. What I'm trying to achieve is, there's a function called `getIds` and it's always possible that function is going to be a loop and until that function is completed the next block of code shouldn't run

```
getIds() {
  for (let r = 0; r < this.grade.length; r++) {
  this.idservice.getIds(this.grade[r])
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response && response.code === HttpStatus.OK) {
        for (let r = 0; r < response.data.length; r++) {
          this.newIds.push({
            id: response.data[r].id
          })
        }

         console.log(this.studentIds)
      }
    }
  );
}
}
```

Now this is the function in which the getIds function is called

```
 createMenu() {
  this.getIds();
//till getIds finishes code underneath shouldn't run

    this.idservice.addNew(this.newIds)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response && response.code === HttpStatus.CREATED) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));

        }
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to use an observable based solution, not async/await, seeing as your `this.idservice.getIds` method returns an observable.

Comment: Look into using rxjs forkJoin.

Comment: @Collierre, can you give me an answer on how it can be done?